# Extract values from layers in terra package

Tags: r, r-raster, terra

I have a `terra::rast` with `n` layers. I would like to extract values for certain layers only with the package `terra` (I prefer answers with this package rather than `raster`). It seems I do not get how to use the argument `layer` in the function `terra::extract`. Here is a minimum (almost) working example:

```r
rs1 = terra::rast(nrows = 3, ncols = 4)
terra::values(rs1) = 4:15
rs2 = terra::rast(nrows = 3, ncols = 4)
terra::values(rs2) = 25:36
rs3 = terra::rast(nrows = 3, ncols = 4)
terra::values(rs3) = 97:108
rs4 = terra::rast(nrows = 3, ncols = 4)
terra::values(rs4) = 51:62

rs = c(rs1, rs2, rs3, rs4)
names(rs) = paste0("layer", 1:nlyr(rs))

coords = matrix(data = c(0, 5, 10, -54, 0, 12), byrow = FALSE, ncol = 2)
colnames(coords) = c("x", "y")

terra::extract(x = rs, y = coords)[, c("layer1", "layer4")] # Works but not elegant in terms of memory
terra::extract(x = rs, y = coords, layer = c("layer1", "layer4")) # Does not work
terra::extract(x = rs, y = coords, layer = c(1, 4)) # Does not work
```

This code provides the following error:

```r
Error in .local(x, y, ...) : length(layer) == nrow(y) is not TRUE
```

I do not understand why the number of layers should equal the number of rows in `y`. I would imagine it should be at max the number of layers in `x`. How to extract the values at the given coordinates for the layers 1 and 4 exclusively (or whatever other layers, this is only an example)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are just looking for the `subset()` function of `terra`. Please find the reprex below.

**Reprex**

```r
library(terra)

extract(x = subset(rs, c(1,4)), y = coords)
#>   layer1 layer4
#> 1     14     61
#> 2     10     57
#> 3     10     57
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Ah yes, I got tricked by the help of the package terra and did not look at subset! This solution works for me thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Glad that I could help. I wish you all the best in your work. Cheers

Comment: You can also do the equivalent  `extract( rs[[ c(1,4) ]],  coords )`

Comment: @Robert Hijmans. Thank you so much for sharing.